# Possible to make runtime changes on emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I am working with the GenyMotion emulator. What I like to do is change a View's background color without having to re reun the application each time. Is it possible to make runtime changes like that(changing a line in the xml file) without having to restart the application to see the changes?

Comment: Not via the xml file, but the program code can change a view's color.

Comment: Can you change program code while the application is running on the emulator?

Comment: Only with difficulty.  But you can certainly have your unchanging program do different things in response to runtime inputs!